# Combining count and flatten functions in scheme

Tags: scheme

So i have these two functions that work fine alone. I am trying to write one function to accomplish both but i keep getting a car error. Any guidance on the best way to solve this?

```
(define (countNumbers lst)
  (cond
 ((null? lst) 0)
 ((number? (car lst))(+ 1 (countNumbers (cdr lst))))
 (else (countNumbers (cdr lst)))))

(define (flatten x)
  (cond ((null? x) '())
        ((pair? x) (append (flatten (car x)) (flatten (cdr x))))
        (else (list x))))
```

I tried something like this im rather new to functional programming in general so im still trying to wrap my mind around it it says the problem is after number?(car lst)

```
(define (flatten lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) '())
        ((pair? lst) (append (flatten (car lst)) (flatten (cdr lst))))
        (else (list(cond
 ((null? lst) 0)
 ((number? (car lst))(+ 1 (flatten (cdr lst))))
 (else (flatten (cdr lst))))))))
```

Comment: Please post the attempted function, pointing where the error is happening. Also notice that it's fine to have two different functions to solve different parts of the problem by composing them; on the other hand sticking everything in a single function doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: You don't need to flatten the list to count the numbers. you can count them directly in a list with sublists. There are many questions here that cover this. just keep in mind, that if the `car` is a `pair?` you need to recure on the `car` and `cdr`

Comment: sorry i phrased it poorly basically my countNumber function counts how many numbers is in a list i am trying to count how many numbers in an arbitrary list like (1 2 (3)) so i need to flatten the list then count the numbers in my new flatten list

Comment: Yes. I understood. Look at the first option given by Oscar. You don't need to traverse the list twice. You can directly count the numbers in an arbitrary list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, I don't think it's a good idea to stick everything in a single function. Anyway, you were kinda on the right track, but we have to remember that if we're going to return a *number* as the final result, then our base case should reflect this and also return a number (not an empty list), and the combining step should *add* numbers, not `append` them. This is what I mean:

```
(define (count-flatten lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) 0)
        ((pair? lst)
         (+ (count-flatten (car lst))
            (count-flatten (cdr lst))))
        ((number? lst) 1)
        (else 0)))
```

But I'd rather do this:

```
(define (count-flatten lst)
  (countNumbers (flatten lst)))
```

We can even write an idiomatic solution using only built-in procedures, check your interpreter's documentation, but in Racket we can do this:

```
(define (count-flatten lst)
  (count number? (flatten lst)))
```

Anyway, it works as expected:

```
(count-flatten '(1 x (x 2) x (3 (4 x (5) 6) 7)))
=> 7
```

Comment: thanks that is what i was trying to do and i see where i messed up.

Comment: it was hepfull and i did my bad im new here and thanks