# How to manage arbitrary list in scheme in regard to adding and counting numbers

Tags: scheme

So i have created basic functions

```
(define (countNumbers lst)
 (cond
 ((null? lst) 0)
 ((number? (car lst))(+ 1 (countNumbers (cdr lst))))
 (else (countNumbers (cdr lst)))))

(define (sumNumbers lst)
 (cond
 ((null? lst) 0)
 ((number? (car lst))(+ (car lst) (sumNumbers (cdr lst))))
 (else (sumNumbers (cdr lst)))))
```

now is there a way and how would you make these functions work for arbitrary list like it i passed in (1 (2 (3))) to countNumbers it returns 3 and if i passed it into sumNumbers it returns 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28311776/201359). In essence, you just have to apply the standard template for traversing a list of lists, doing what's appropriate depending on the problem:

1. Test for the `null?` list, base case.
2. Test if the current element is a `pair?`, in this case we have to recur over the `car` and the `cdr` and combine the answers.
3. Else, we're in an atom.

Additionally, for the functions that you mention we have to test for an additional case: if the current atom is or isn't a `number?`; and the way of *combining* here is by adding the results. For example:

```
(define (countNumbers lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) 0)
        ((pair? lst)
         (+ (countNumbers (car lst))
            (countNumbers (cdr lst))))
        ((number? lst) 1)
        (else 0)))

(define (sumNumbers lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) 0)
        ((pair? lst)
         (+ (sumNumbers (car lst))
            (sumNumbers (cdr lst))))
        ((number? lst) lst)
        (else 0)))
```

It works as expected:

```
(countNumbers '(1 x (x 2) x (3 (4 x (5) 6) 7)))
=> 7

(sumNumbers '(1 x (x 2) x (3 (4 x (5) 6) 7)))
=> 28
```

Answer (score 1):

### Higher Level of Abstraction

Rather than using the lower level operators `car` and `cdr` which have their origins in the machine instructions of the IBM 704, `countNumbers` can be implemented at a higher level of abstraction using [function composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) and [sequences as conventional interfaces](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/sicp/book/node35.html) as described in [*The Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs*](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/sicp/book/node1.html):

```
(define (countNumbers lox)
  (length (filter number? (flatten lox))))
```

### Implementing Flatten

`flatten` is a common list operation. But it is not included in the scheme standard.

From [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Flatten_a_list#Scheme):

```
 (define (flatten x)
    (cond ((null? x) '())
          ((not (pair? x)) (list x))
          (else (append (flatten (car x))
                        (flatten (cdr x))))))
```

The [source](https://github.com/plt/racket/blob/73f4fa86a3304b34437c0a1b94ea0e14f6f62de0/racket/collects/racket/list.rkt) for `#lang racket` built in `flatten` offers a faster implementation based on iteration and `cons`:

```
(define (flatten orig-sexp)
  (let loop ([sexp orig-sexp] [acc null])
    (cond [(null? sexp) acc]
      [(pair? sexp) (loop (car sexp) (loop (cdr sexp) acc))]
      [else (cons sexp acc)])))
```

In R5RS Scheme this would be:

```
(define (flatten orig-sexp)
  (letrec 
      ((loop (lambda (sexp acc)
               (cond ((null? sexp) acc)
                     ((pair? sexp)
                      (loop (car sexp)
                            (loop (cdr sexp) acc)))
                     (else (cons sexp acc))))))
    (loop orig-sexp '())))
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good implementation. You traverse the list 3 times. by flatten, filter and finally length. In addition to this, flatten uses append, that in turn traverses the entire list.

Comment: @Rptx The goal is to illustrate a higher level approach to solving the problem, e.g. one that prioritizes readability and clarity.  The Rosetta Code implementation is provided only for completeness as R5RS does not include `flatten`.  Other Schemes such as `chicken` and `#lang racket` include `flatten`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a second level of recursion, like this:

```lisp
(define (countNumbers lst)
  (cond
   ((null? lst) 0)
   ((number? (car lst))(+ 1 (countNumbers (cdr lst))))
   ((list? (car lst)) (+ (countNumbers (car lst)) (countNumbers (cdr lst))))
   (else (countNumbers (cdr lst)))))

(define (sumNumbers lst)
  (cond
   ((null? lst) 0)
   ((number? (car lst))(+ (car lst) (sumNumbers (cdr lst))))
   ((list? (car lst)) (+ (sumNumbers (car lst)) (sumNumbers (cdr lst))))
   (else (sumNumbers (cdr lst)))))
```